# Does this sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this series converge?

$$s_T=\frac{1+2^a+3^a+\cdots+T^a}{T}\text{ where }a>0.$$ 
I think it diverges for any $a>0$, because 
$$\frac{1+2^a+3^a+\cdots+T^a}{T} \ge \int^{T+1}_{x=1} (x-1)^a \frac{dx}{T}=\frac{T^{a}}{a+1}\to+\infty\text{ as }T\to+\infty.$$

Is this a right way to prove it? I'd be happy if anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: If I were to try this, I would try doing it with induction, showing that it works with a=1 and then if a=m, and works, that a=m+1 works, and by the axiom of induction proving it. There might be an easier/better way to do it, but induction was what came to me first.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that way to be confident with my proof.

Comment: Much simpler: $$\frac{1 + 2^a + \dots + T^a}{T} \ge \frac{T^a}{T} = T^{a - 1} \to \infty$$ if $a > 1$; for $a= 1$ the sum is known

Comment: Well written up. Maybe go from $0$ to $T$, and $x^a$. Less typing.

Answer (score 3):

Another way for even $T$:
$$\frac{[1^a + \cdots + (T/2)^a] + [ (T/2+1)^a + \cdots + T^a]}{T} \geq \frac{[0] + [(T/2)^a + \cdots + (T/2)^a]}{T} \\ = \frac{(T/2)^a(T/2)}{T} = T^a/2^{a+1}$$
where the second expression is the sum of $(T/2)^a$ added together $T/2$ times.

P.S. The principle of what you are doing in your question is fine. I'm too lazy to check that the bounds are all correct.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot easily see where the inequality come from, can you explain?

Comment: Wow, super easy way! thank you very much.

Comment: @enzotib, does the edit help now? One set of terms is dropped and the second one is bounded from below.

Comment: It is ok now, thank you.